# How can I make a Multilistbox using grid_rowconfigure & grid_columnconfigure

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to make a Multilistbox using grid_columnconfigure & grid_rowconfigure. I have the following code and it does not work when I Maximize the window because I do not know how can I set columnconfigure and rowconfigure in Multilistbox.

My Code works like this when I maximize the window:
[Working Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzQ6H.png)

My expection like this when I will maximize the window:
[expected result when I will maximize the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOTDY.png)
My code is here:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MultiListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lists = []
        Label(self,text="Product Name",borderwidth=1,
              relief=RAISED).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6,sticky=N + S + E + W)
        Label(self,text="Product Name",borderwidth=1,
              relief=RAISED).grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=1,sticky=N + S + E + W)
        Label(self,text="Product Name",borderwidth=1,
              relief=RAISED).grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky=N + S + E + W)
        Label(self,text="Product Name",borderwidth=1,
              relief=RAISED).grid(row=1,column=4,columnspan=2,sticky=N + S + E + W)
        for num, (l, w) in enumerate(lists):
            frame = Frame(self)
            frame.grid(row=2,column=num)
            Label(frame, text=l, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N + S + E + W)
            lb = Listbox(frame, width=w, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                         relief=FLAT, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.grid(row=1,column=0)
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
        Label(self, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED, text=" ").grid(row=0,column=7,sticky=N + S + E + W,rowspan=3)
        sb = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        sb.grid(row=2,column=7,sticky="ns")
        self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand'] = sb.set

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    Label(tk, text='MultiListbox').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(tk, (('Quantity', 20), ('Price', 20), ('Quantity', 20), ('Price', 20),('Quantity', 20), ('Price', 20),))
    mlb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"I do not know how can I set columnconfigure and rowconfigure in Multilistbox"_ - why don't you know that? You're clearly using rowconfigure and columnconfigure in other places. Why is doing it in MultiListbox any different? Also, are you only asking about MultiListbox? If so, you should remove the other code from your example so we can focus on it.

Comment: I remove the other code from my example. I'm trying to set rowconfigure and columnconfigure but it does'nt work properly. I need your help.

Comment: ***" trying to set `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`"***: I see no `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`. You are using `mlb.pack(...` therefore `grid` configure does not help either.

Comment: @stovfl: The OP is using `grid` inside MultiListbox, so that is what needs the calls to `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are those screenshots accurate representations of what you want? It looks strange that the first `Product Name` is only over one column, then the next is over three columns, then the next is over two columns.

Comment: There are couple problems here. Missing `grid_...configure`, `sticky='nswe'` and no `yview` connection. Also more `Label` than Columns, inconsisten `column=` values and `columnspan=` values.